# When have to call Server to get data?

Tags: server, client

In case of automatic hunting like mobile games, I implemented Auto-combat system in the client, and every single use a skills, the player character's stats are loaded from the server.(like player's attack range)
The tick to use the skill is 0.5 seconds. I thought this was the problem

So I try to build a new one

1. Load DB at the time the unit is created or specific Event(Join field, Change Channel...) and create an instance for use in Client.
2. Automatic combat are managed by the server.

I don't know how to do it optimization effectively and prevent Client cheating...

Comment: it is unclear what problem you are seeing? ... it apperas that you are saying that you do not get data from the server in a timely fashion ... but then you mention client cheating ... the two appear unrelated

Comment: Yes. it can't get data from the server in a timely fashion.. but if get data when create unit class in client. I thought about client cheating